# Not able to execute bash script using spawn

Tags: bash, expect, spawn

I have a script that has the following:

```
   #!/usr/bin/expect
   spawn /user/home/scripts/shutdown.sh
   expect "password\r"
```

I am trying to execute the script --> ./scriptname

But the shutdown.sh script does not execute. Any clue about this?

Comment: Why are you asking `expect` to run the script? You could just run `/user/home/scripts/shutdown.sh` directly. Are you sure about the path to shutdown.sh?

Comment: What error message to do you get when you run your expect script?

Comment: How do you know that the script did run?

Comment: try catching any spawn errors with `if [ catch "spawn /user/home/scripts/shutdown.sh" reason ] { puts "failed to spawn shutdown.sh $reason" }`

Comment: I am usingexpect because I need to provide a password to run the script.

Comment: I know the script didn't run because the service that I ma trying to shutdown is still running.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch spawn errors like so ...

```
if [ catch "spawn /user/home/scripts/shutdown.sh" reason ] {
   puts "Could not spawn shutdown.sh $reason"
}
```

... that way you can see there were indeed any errors spawn your script.